# TrustedInstaller.exe is eating all CPU; 100%

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, updates, cpu-usage

I have bought an ASUS ux50v for my wife (so pleeeeeaaaase help!), it has a single core cpu and Windows 7 Home Premium installed. I have updated it's os (made a mistake?) and now this TrustedInstaller.exe thing (used by Windows Module Installer or something like that; related to windows update) is screwing the whole system without logging/prompting/announcing what the heck it is up to.

Anyone had the same problem and solved it?

Edit 1: In action center>problem report I'v found a lot of repeated windowswcpotherfailure3. What's that?

Edit 2: I ran sfc.exe /scannow and it says:
Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation.

Edit 3: I restored Windows 7 to an earlier restore point and the problems gone (or maybe I would do a factory restore by DVDs); but I did not figured out what was the cause.

And I am afraid of trying again to update Windows 7!

Edit 4: I have found a [blog entry](http://d3dal3.blogspot.com/2010/07/unable-to-add-new-components-in-windows.html) that describes a similar problem. The error message (for WindowsWcpOtherFailure3...) is the same; but my default language is English on this laptop. Why should I get that problem?

Edit 5: I gave up; restored to factory setting with recovery DVDs; turned off Windows Updates :(

Comment: Wife mode: swap enabled, PowerStrip/other software cleanses fragmented RAM, sets low priority to unwanted processes, etc etc etc.

Comment: You are so funny; you know!

Comment: Just for the record all problems from back then, solved by installing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

It often happens that TrustedInstaller takes 100% CPU as it's continuously working on updates. I usually leave it running for some hours (more than 10) with Internet connection enabled. After that, I try to reboot up to twice. The problem should not occur any more.

As yours is a new laptop, I would always suggest a Windows clean install by a clean **retail** version, not the vendor-customized ones with lots of garbage software shipped with it. A **warez** version, believe me, is ok because you have a Windows license when you have bought your laptop. Be sure that you install the version you are legitimated to use, and not the Ultimate because **that** will be bad.

Comment: Thanks!Where can I find a secure, not altered one?

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell you. There is a thin *red line* dividing what's legal from what's illegal. I can't go beyond that line. No one here can. You have to search by yourself, without any help. :(

Comment: I did not knew the meaning of warez! 8) You are right. For now; I just struggle with it. After all there must be a solution; "I have paid for it"! Thanks again!

Comment: No need to talk about "warez". He can download Windows 7 from Digital River legitimately. Totally unnecessary to go looking for torrents for something you can easily get here: http://www.mydigitallife.info/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-from-digital-river/

Comment: What's bad, Microsoft told me that built-in version of Windows (full of bloatware) is not the (legally) same as retail Windows from OEM disk. That is, I only have a right to install built-in version, and even if I wiped partition that consisted that bloatwared version I have no way of intalling it but to contact my notebook vendor and pay for giving me that 'their' version. Can't say I agree with that approach. What I'd like to get along with my notebook is Windows OEM disk AND another disk with drivers (separated one by one, not huge archive of all drivers and bloatware together).

Answer (score 1):

Trusted installer is used by Windows Update to install updates.  if you go to the control panel, and back to windows update, are you still installing updates in the background?

Comment: Yes; it's still working :(